# Were blood screenings ever an effective way to test for changelings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In DS9, the concept of bleeding to test for changelings is introduced by Gowron, who seems convinced that taking blood is an effective countermeasure to changeling incursion.

However, during the full-scale changeling invasion, it's revealed that Julian Bashir was a Changeling for at least a month, while the real Bashir is in a Dominion internment camp.

Did the blood screenings ever actually work as a way to detect changelings?  Or was the idea that they worked just a falsehood encouraged by the Dominion?

Comment: A side note: You initial assumption is a bit incorrect. You're talking about events shown in first episode of fourth season of DS9, while actually blood screening idea comes from the last episode of third season of DS9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods of [blood screening](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Blood_screening) seen on screen appear to have been ineffective at detecting changlings.

Using hyposprays seemed to provide changlings with an easy means of creating false positives. Twice we witnessed a changling falsely implicate someone else during a screening: [Commander Eddington](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Adversary_%28episode%29) on the Defiant and later [Sisko](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Paradise_Lost_%28episode%29) on Earth.

The Klingon method of simply cutting the skin and letting blood drip out also appears to have been ineffective, as [General Martok](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_%28episode%29), the first Klingon we see use this method, was replaced with a changling himself.

Comment: And during Eddington's false positive, he successfully faked being Bashir.  (And Sisko's father even explained, the first time it was used on Earth, why it wouldn't work)

Comment: It seems likely, especially given the success of the Martok Changeling in staying undercover for as long as he did, that the idea that blood screenings would ever work on Changelings was a piece of disinformation spread by the Changelings themselves. Quite possibly by the Martok Changeling, given his high status in the Klingon Empire.

Comment: The blood screenings do require the changeling to have stored some blood internally, because otherwise, any small part of a changeling separated from the main reverts to liquid form.

Comment: The Sisko situation doesn't apply - that was a case of humans falsely implicating someone AS a changeling. No changeling was involved in that situation. The obvious indicator is Martok, however. We saw the Martok changeling pass a blood test at least twice.